# using interfaces in systemverilog?

Tags: system-verilog

i have written a code in system verilog for interface. but it  it giving me the error at clk. the error is Undefined variable clk....
code is 
error at always(posedge clk)

```
   interface simple_bus(input logic clk);  
     // Define the interface   
     logic req, gnt; 
     logic [7:0] addr, data; 
     logic [1:0] mode; 
     logic start, rdy; 
   endinterface: simple_bus 

   module memMod(simple_bus a); 
     // simple_bus interface port logic avail; 
     //logic clk; 
     always @(posedge clk) 
     a.gnt <= a.req & avail; 
   endmodule
```

when using clock in always block it is giving the error **"Undefined variable: clk"**

Comment: Why did you comment out the definition of the clk signal? `logic clk` in line 3 of memMod? You need to uncomment it so to avoid the error. Once you uncomment it, you still need to somehow drive it possibly from another always block or from a primary input port of memMod.

Comment: thank you, it worked i have made it in two ways by making as input and bit clk

Answer (score 1):

`clk` is input to the given interface `simple_bus`, you need to hierarchically access it. Such as `a.clk`.

So your module code would be:

```
   module memMod(simple_bus a); 
     always @(posedge a.clk) 
       a.gnt <= a.req & avail; 
   endmodule
```

**Edit:**
I have tried your code at my end and it's working. PFB exa code.

```
interface simple_bus(input logic clk);  
     // Define the interface   
     logic req, gnt; 
     logic [7:0] addr, data; 
     logic [1:0] mode; 
     logic start, rdy; 
endinterface: simple_bus 

module memMod(simple_bus a); 
  // simple_bus interface port logic avail; 
  //logic clk; 
  always @(posedge a.clk) a.gnt <= a.req; 
endmodule

module main();
  logic clk;

  simple_bus sb(clk);
  memMod m(sb);

  initial repeat(10) clk = #5 ~clk;
endmodule
```

Comment: Now i am getting error at poedege a.clk Error: (vlog-13069) C:/Users/venkat/Desktop/New folder/systemverilog/second.sv(9): near ".": syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')'.

Comment: @venkatpasumarthi What is `avail`?